# Insert special characters into SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert, special-characters

`The ' ' character cannot be included in a name.`

I use a log manager to log the error to SQL Server 2008 database. Of course, it will raise another error in the SQL Server because it contains special characters`' '` . So what is the best way to handle special characters in SQL Server.

Comment: You're having a problem storing a space character in a SQL Server column?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using a space in an XML name. Correct your XML code to not have spaces in any tag names, this isn't SQL Server 2008 specific.

Comment: Please see the text 'So what is the best way to handle special characters in SQL Server'. I know the `' '` is there. I want to know the best way to handle this type of special characters in SQL Server. Ohkie ? :)

Comment: I am letting you know that you are not understanding what the error is correctly. This error should be corrected in a location not related to the SQL Server.

Comment: @Rauf: Nick is 100% correct. XML does not allow spaces in element names. It is *not* a SQL Server problem. Remove spaces before sending to SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

To get a column to handle special characters define it as a NVARCHAR instead of a VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague.  Do you want to *prevent* the user from having a space?  And if so, do you want to not allow there to be a space character, or just get the space character out?  If so, do something like `replace(@yourInputString, ' ', '')`.

If this is not what you are looking for, please clarify your question and your exact requirements.