# Inserting special characters into SQL Server 2008 RE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am reading some data from a database table and the text contains the '/' character.

I now need to insert this string into a different SQL table but I'm having problems escaping it correctly.

If the string I read contains this pattern:

> Test/test2

After some google searching, I am using to insert the text
(google refs [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228833/insert-special-characters-into-sql-server-2008-database/%22ref1%22) and [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228833/insert-special-characters-into-sql-server-2008-database))

```
Field1= replace (cast('Test/th' as nvarchar),'/','\\\')
```

But it still returns the error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Line 18
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

If I use:

```
Field1= replace (cast('Test/th' as nvarchar),'/','')
```

Everything is fine

Can anyone help me with my escape clause please?

Comment: That error would indicate that you are trying to store a string longer than the column will accept. I don't think this has anything to do with special characters. What is the definition of `Field1`? You should also use a length with `NVARCHAR` in your convert, e.g. `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), 'Test/th')`

Comment: What is the point of that first replace? You are changing all instances of a forward slash with....a forward slash.

Comment: Sorry you are correct it was meant to be \

Answer (score 0):

I think your column field length is set to 6. Change it to 7.